# Tangents to a function and its inverse

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

I came across the following problem:

Find all $x$ values such that the tangent to the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+1} + (1-2x)^{1/3}$ where $x \ge 0$ at that $x$ value is perpendicular to the tangent of its inverse function $f^{-1}(x)$ at that $x$ value.

I know that a formula for the  derivative of the inverse function is
$(f^{-1})^{'}(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$ and we want this expression for $(f^{-1})^{'}(x)$ to be the negative reciprocal of $f'(x)$ for the tangent of the function to be perpendicular to the tangent of its inverse at $x$. This gives the equation $f'(x) = -f'(f^{-1}(x))$. However, it seems the only way to solve this equation for $x$ is to find $f^{-1}(x)$ explicitly and I can't seem to find the inverse of $f$ because it is so complicated. I tried the standard swapping $y$ and $x$ and solving for $y$ trick. I even tried Wolfram Alpha but it didn't seem to find an answer in terms of elementary functions.

Is there a way to solve this problem without explicitly finding the inverse or, if not, how would one go about finding the inverse of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+1} + (1-2x)^{1/3}$ where $x \ge 0$ ?

Comment: Just an idea... I was thinking to integrate the relation $f(x) = -f'(f^{-1}(x))$ and then use a change of variable $x = f(t)$ so the integral on the left is expressed only in $f$, from here integrate by parts, after some calculations you reach an equation only in $f(x)$ but it's not very cute. I don't think that you could really evaluate an inverse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such $x$. The function $f$ is strictly decreasing and any tangent line to its graph has negative slope, with one exception: the tangent line at $\left(\frac12,\frac45\right)$ is a vertical line. So, $f^{-1}$ is strictly decreasing too and any tangent line to its graph has negative slope, again with one exception: the tangent line at $\left(\frac45,\frac12\right)$ is a horizontal line. So, these two lines are the only example of a tangent line to the graph of $f$ and a tangent line to the graph of $f^{-1}$ which are perpendicular. But $\frac45\ne\frac12$, and so the problem has no solution.

Comment: Ah I see. I was trying to think of a specific property of this problem that would help me solve it and didn't realize the importance of it being strictly decreasing.